# Where is the tmux command for choose-window?

Tags: tmux

Learning tmux and one of the first things the book tells you to find in the key bindings (ctrl+b ?) using (ctrl+s) is 'choose-window' but that doesn't exist.  There is a choose-tree (2 actually [ctrl+b + w] or [ctrl+b + s]).  I cannot find anywhere that differentiates these or explains that one replaces choose-window even though ctrl+b+w seems to operate as choose-window. Can anyone confirm or refute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

choose-window was replaced by choose-tree in version 2.6.
Now, instead of showing all panes from the current session it shows a tree view of all panes in all sessions.
To get the old behavior you can put this in your .tmux.conf:

> bind-key w run-shell 'tmux choose-tree -Nwf"##{==:##{session_name},#{session_name}}"'

(taken from https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1115)

Comment: Cheers @Jakob Erdmann, any idea on [how to customize the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937438/tmux-how-to-filter-the-current-session-windows-using-choose-tree-and-format-the)