# Tmux: How to filter the current session windows using choose-tree and format the output to show windows names without hostname

Tags: shell, terminal, formatting, format, tmux

I would like to configure `tmux choose-tree` to **show windows for my current session only**.

But in the meantime I want to **keep the formatting I currently use (window name without hostname)**:
My current setup is:

```
bind-key w choose-tree -F "#{window_name}"
```

And look like this:

[image: Current output]

[I found the following config which filters the windows of my current session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49911496/where-is-the-tmux-command-for-choose-window):

```
bind-key w run-shell 'tmux choose-tree -Nwf"##{==:##{session_name},#{session_name}}"'
```

However, I do not manage to format the output as I want…

[image: Working filtering without desired output]

I tried mixing the 2 commands, but the output is not working as expected (it prints the active window for each window...):

```
bind-key w run-shell 'tmux choose-tree -Nwf"##{==:##{session_name},#{session_name}}" -F "#{window_name}"'
```

[image: Working filtering with wrong formatting output]

How can I use filter `-f` and formatter `-F` options together to produce the desired output?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`run-shell` replaces certain strings before passing the command on to the shell, as explained in the man page. You can see this in your example which has both `##{session_name}` and `#{session_name}`.

The first expression has the `##` replaced by `#` resulting in the final string `#{session_name}`, whereas the second has the entire string replaced by the current value of the tmux variable `#{session_name}`, which might for example be `"www"`. This means `choose-tree` is actually called with argument `-Nwf"#{==:#{session_name},www}"`.

You need to do the same with the `-F` expression, doubling the `#` so that the string is not expanded to the current value of `window_name`. So try `-F "##{window_name}"`.